# celery: chord and group in chain not working correctly

Tags: python, celery

I am doing same tasks that needs to reuse the result computed by previous tasks. More specifically, I have three models, and there are two steps of, the first step is clean and segment raw data, the second tasks are two different kind of tokenizations. Two of the model share the same tokenizer, and the third one requires the result computed by the second tokenizer. Hence I first need to clean and segment the raw input, which are later relay to the tokenizers, and one of the tokenized result are fed to two models, and the other one are to be fed to the last model. Lastly, I need to combine the result.

However, I can't seem to make the tasks to work. Model prediction tasks were run, but they can't be all passed to the last combining task. I simply the task as the following.

```
@app.route('test', methods = ['GET'])
def test():
   result = test_chain_group.delay(10)
   result = [v for v in result.collect()]

   return str(result)

@shared_task
def test_chain_group(num):
        header = [(add.s(5) | group([add.s(6), mul.s(9)])), (mul.s(5)|add.s(3))]
        chord_r = chord(header, aggr.s())
        chain_r = (add.s(7)|chord_r)
        result = chain_r(num)
        return result

@shared_task
def add(a,b):
        return a+b
@shared_task
def mul(a,b):
        return a*b

@shared_task
def aggr1(data):
    return data
```

Though the worker computed 28, 198, 88 correctly, but only 28 and 198 were passed to aggr1. Also the flask app didn't wait for the result to come back before returning something to the client.